# Is there a way to synchronize entities between 2 databases?

Tags: mysql, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have two databases on different sites with the same rather complex schema.
Is there a way to take single user and his entities and move everything to another database?

I tried JMSSerializer and it's symfony bundle. Every time I have different errors trying to import 'parent' object, I believe that these errors I have because of circular references. Serializing each single object for certain user in 'relations chain' is too complex for export and import.

So I'd like to know if there an intelligent tool for merging two mysql databases, probably with doctrine support or something else...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a one-time sync?  (mysqldump + mysql)  Or do you want things to be continually kept in sync?  (replication)

Comment: @Rick Yes, it's one-time sync for set of values(but not all) in db.